# Updated Visual Studio 2022 Preview to 17.2.0 preview 3 from 2.1 issue building

Tags: android, build, reference, preview, maui

I usually build to an android emulator without any issues until the latest update. Now I get this error:
Error   NETSDK1130  Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.winmd cannot be referenced. Referencing a Windows Metadata component directly when targeting .NET 5 or higher is not supported.

I have made sure all nuget packages are fully up to date.
As far as I know references in the C# project look fine:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows'))">
        <!-- Required - WinUI does not yet have buildTransitive for everything -->
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D" Version="1.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>


    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D" Version="1.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.0.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
      <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.0.7" />
      <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.0.7" />
      <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.0.7" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Nothing else has changed. Anyone have a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps for me:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-to-RC1

I went through all steps for upgrading since "Migrate to Preview 13"

Comment: Thank you, I know Gerald posted the notes too and I just was looking over it. I'm not going to lie, I haven't really been changing too much in my .net maui project after upgrading last few times. Hope I didn't miss too many things. Everything is up and running right now. Appreciate the response. I'll have to keep an eye out for the wiki guides as I update.

Answer (score 2):

First, you specified these lines twice and one with different version numbers:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D" Version="1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.0.2" />
```

Second, this looks like an older template, aka you have started this project with an earlier preview. That is fine, but then for each update have a close look at what is needed to migrate your project to work with the latest version. For instance, here is [the notes for RC1](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-to-RC1). Specifically for these packages it mentions:

> These are no longer needed in your csproj
>
> ```xml
> <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows'))">
>   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.0.0" />
>   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D" Version="1.0.0.30" />
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

Comment: After removing this first itemgroup I am still getting the same error NETSDK1130 Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.winmd cannot be referenced. Referencing a Windows Metadata component directly when targeting .NET 5 or higher is not supported. I will continue to look into what else was needed for project upgrade. Let me know if anything else comes to mind.